# Can you use Linear-gradient property to do VERTICAL background color

Tags: html, css, background-color

So here is what I am trying:

```
body {
    height:100%;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #DB2B39 50%, #2B303A 50%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #DB2B39 50%,#2B303A 50%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #DB2B39 50%,#2B303A 50%);
}
```

[image: Vertical colors]

But THAT is producing only a horizontal split, and it seems odd that yo can't easily do it vertically without it being stripes.

Am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: I made a CodePen with some more complex repeating gradients for those who are interested https://codepen.io/ScarpMetal/pen/yLZmLxO

Answer (score 0):

That's making a horizontal gradient because you're setting the `angle` to "to right". If you put instead `to bottom` or `top` it will generate a vertical gradient.

```
body {
    height:100%;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #DB2B39 50%, #2B303A 50%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #DB2B39 50%,#2B303A 50%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #DB2B39 50%,#2B303A 50%);
}
```

Please check all the values for linear-gradient [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the value "fixed". See below.

```
body {
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(219,43,57,1) 50%,rgba(43,48,58,1) 50%,rgba(10,8,9,1) 50%) fixed; 
}
```

http://codepen.io/adamfollett/pen/YWBmxR

Comment: Thank you this is perfect :D